# Как отменить загрузку файлов на гит?

Tags: git

В папке сервера, есть директория с загрузками, забыл поставить ее в гитигнор, сделал

```
git add ./server
```

ну и сделал коммит.Дальше пытался запушить(еще не увидел своей ошибки), но там есть файлы свыше 100 мб и конечно словил предупреждение и отмену загрузки. Дальше пробовал git reset и git reset HEAD~, и после того как поставил в гитигнор папку с загрузками и удаляю не нужную директорию вручную, наново добавляю сервер в гит, он пытается загрузить дальше уже не существующий большой файл. Важно сохранить изменения в коде и убрать из гита файлы которые он пытается грузить?

При загрузке получаю в консоль:

[image: Изображение]

Директории локально уже не существует, да, ошибся и не удалил из индекса изначально.
Команда: `git rm ./server/uploads` уже не видит директории

Comment: Посмотрите `git log --name-status`  Возможно большие файлы появились раньше

Comment: дело не в этом, а в том что я не могу удалить их из индекса, и локально я их снес по незнанке

Comment: `git rm --cached ./server/uploads` это что ли надо?

Comment: нет, я же удалил вручную директорию, оон просто теперь не находит ее с помощью этой команды и получаю  fatal: pathspec 'server/uploads' did not match any files

Comment: Ну добавьте `-f`